# Plot non-linear relation as a straight line

Tags: calculus

I have this relation between the data $x$ and $y$:
$$y = a + \frac{b}{x}$$ and I would now like to form a straight line from the data. When I have for example $y = a \cdot r^b$ then one can plot $log(y)$ as a function of $log(r)$ because of $log(y) = log(a) + b \cdot log(r)$, but in this case I don't know how to rewrite the function. I would also like to find the slope coefficient of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't have $x=0$ you can plot $y = a+ bt$ where $t = 1/x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same trick since $\log(y-a) = \log(b) - \log(x)$ (provided there is no problem with the signs...). The slope is then $-1$.